# How to build A matrix for this argmin E problem to constraint vertex symmetrically distributed in a mesh

Tags: eigen, mesh, least-squares, laplacian

How to build A matrix for the argmin E=∑||N×(v_i-v_j)||^2 by solving it in a least square sense?

this energy is designed for constrainting vertex symmetrically distributed in both sides of the symmetric plane of a mesh, where N(a,b,c) is the normal of the plane (N is given), and "×" is the cross product. v_i and v_j is a pair of symmetric vertices.

To solve the energy minimization in a least square sense, E should be written as ||Ax-B||^2, where x is mesh vertex matrix(n vertices).

The question is I cannot find a proper A to build the Ax-B.

Similar as a Laplace matrix (n*n), I think the size of A should be ?*n, since in some cases we also need to minimize E=||L(v)||^2 to keep smoothness, and the Laplace matrix will link with this A matrix which obtains something like (LT*L+AT*A)X=AT*b in final code of Eigen to solve the problem.

I want to know how to build A matrix. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: This sounds more like a [math.se] problem than a programming problem at the moment. Once you know what to put into your matrix, but have trouble expressing this in Eigen, you can come back here.